# Programmatically access Tags in Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am building an application that creates Teams for my training classes and I can Create a Group, make it a team, and then add the required folks to the Members list. I want to be able to differentiate between "students" and "facilitators" for reporting and management.

I have found `/api/v1/teams/{0}/memberTags/` but I don't seem to be able to call it directly or find it in the SDK documentation.

Is this API available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Teams Tags** are currently in the Graph beta
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teamworktag

Tags provide a flexible way for customers to classify users or groups based on a common attribute within a team. For example, a Nurse or Manager or Designer tag will enable users to reach groups of people in Teams without having to type every single name.

Tags are scoped at the Team level.

When a tag is added, users can @mention it (@tag) in a channel in that team . Everyone who has been assigned that tag will receive a notification just as they would if they were @mentioned individually. Users can also use a tag is to start a new chat with the members of that tag.

Answer (score 0):

No, there’s no API for this now .

Check here to [Manage tags in Microsoft Teams app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/manage-tags#add-tags-in-teams). We will keep you posted once this feature is available through API.